# MySQL how to sum amount of excessive transactions in any 15 minute window?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, inner-join, self-join

MySQL

```
create table tran(
  id int,
  tran_dt datetime, 
  card_id int,
  merchant_id int,
  amount int
);

#Customer #1 
insert into tran values(11, '2015-01-01 01:59:00', 1, 1, 2);
insert into tran values(12, '2015-01-01 02:01:00', 1, 1, 4);
insert into tran values(13, '2015-01-01 02:02:00', 1, 1, 6);

#Customer #2 
insert into tran values(21, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 2, 1, 10);
insert into tran values(22, '2015-01-01 01:01:00', 2, 1, 20);
insert into tran values(23, '2015-01-01 01:02:00', 2, 1, 30);
insert into tran values(24, '2015-01-01 01:03:00', 2, 1, 20);
insert into tran values(29, '2015-01-02 01:03:00', 2, 1, 10);

#Customer #3 
insert into tran values(31, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 3, 1, 100);
insert into tran values(32, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 3, 1, 200);
insert into tran values(33, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 3, 1, 100);
insert into tran values(34, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 3, 1, 200);
insert into tran values(35, '2015-01-01 01:00:00', 3, 1, 100);
```

A report of which cards have been used 3+ times in any 15 minute window at the same merchant:

```
SELECT t1.card_id, t1.merchant_id, count(distinct t1.id)+1 as Count, sum(t1.amount) 'SumAmount'
FROM tran t1 
INNER JOIN tran t2
on t2.card_id=t1.card_id 
  and t2.merchant_id=t1.merchant_id 
  and t2.tran_dt <= DATE_ADD(t1.tran_dt, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
  and t2.id>t1.id
GROUP BY t1.card_id,t1.merchant_id
HAVING Count>2;
```

The query now works perfectly at counting cards.

Lastly, I am trying to add a column called `SumAmount` to also give a sum of the amounts. But `SumAmount` shows wrong logarithmically large amounts, because its a self-join. I think I would need the sum only on *distinct* row IDs, just like the `Count` column. How can `SumAmount` be fixed?

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bbd0/6

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a little off, because it is missing the transaction id.  But, your real issue is that you want to sum the amount from `t2` and not `t1`:

```
SELECT t1.card_id, t1.merchant_id, t1.tran_dt,
       count(distinct t2.id) + 1 as Count, sum(t2.amount) as SumAmount
FROM tran t1 INNER JOIN
     tran t2
     on t2.card_id = t1.card_id and
        t2.merchant_id = t1.merchant_id and
        t2.tran_dt >= t1.tran_dt and
        t2.tran_dt <= DATE_ADD(t1.tran_dt, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) 
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.card_id, t1.merchant_id, t1.tran_dt
HAVING Count > 2;
```

Note:  I changed the `join` condition from `>` to `>=` to include the first transaction.  Also, I added the `>=` on the date, and changed the count in `SELECT` to be for the second table, not the first.

Comment: brings back too many rows after fixing typo on trans_dt to tran_dt in grp by

Comment: @DrewPierce . . . For customer 3, you are going to get a row for each transaction.

Comment: This [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/597ff/1) from earlier today ... the OP wants to add a sum on the amount column. Haven't had time to do any of it, just wanted to give you feedback.

Comment: @DrewPierce . . . This query brings back every transaction that has two more transactions within 15 minutes (as well as the sum).  This will involve duplicates, when there are more than 3 transactions within 15 minutes.  It is unclear to me whether the problem of duplicates in the results really needs to be solved (the issue in the query was that part of the sequential logic used `tran_dt` and another part used `id`; only the date should be used.)

Comment: Where did you do this: "I changed the join condition from > to >=" ?

Comment: @davidjhp . . . Because the condition is counting 3 or more.  So, the original transaction should be included.  This is important for the `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.card_id, a.merchant_id, MAX(cases_count) AS cases_count, MAX(sum_of_amount) AS sum_of_amount
FROM
(
SELECT t1.id, t1.card_id,t1.merchant_id, count(*) AS cases_count, sum(t2.amount) AS sum_of_amount
FROM tran t1 
INNER JOIN tran t2
ON t2.card_id=t1.card_id 
AND t2.merchant_id=t1.merchant_id 
AND (t2.tran_dt <= DATE_ADD(t1.tran_dt, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
AND t2.tran_dt >= t1.tran_dt )
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.card_id,t1.merchant_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) AS a
GROUP BY a.card_id, a.merchant_id
```